# How can I use vector or algorithm for finding maximum amount in this code?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I wrote following code for finding maximum score:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

constexpr int MAX_STUDENTS = 3;

using namespace std;
class student{
public:
    void vrod();
    void dis();
    int stno;
    int score
    int i;
    string name;
};

void student::vrod(){
    cout << "name=";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "stno=";
    cin >> stno;
    cout << "score=";
    cin >> score;
}
void student::dis(){
    cout << "name=" << name << "\n" << "stno=" << stno << "\n" << "score=" << score<< "\n";
    cin.get();
}

int main(){
    int l;
    vector<student> my_vector;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        student new_student;
        cout << "Number: ";
        cin >> new_student.stno;
        cout << "Score: ";
        cin >> new_student.score;
        cout << "Name: ";
        cin >> new_student.name;

        my_vector.push_back(new_student);
    }

    l=0;
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_STUDENTS; ++i)
    {
        if (my_vector[i].score>l) {
            l=my_vector[i].score;
        }
    }

    cout << "max=" << l;

    cin.get();
    cin.get();
}
```

I used common ways to find maximum amount, but how can I use vector? how about algorithm? I found that there is a function which is max in algorithm, but it needs two argument and I could not use that for this code. Thanks for your tips beforehand.

Comment: use `max_element` instead of `max`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) and a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) expression for the comparator:

```
auto l = std::max_element(my_vector.cbegin(), my_vector.cend(),
    [](const student& s1, const student& s2) {
    return s1.score < s2.score;
    });
```

`l` is a const iterator, to output maximum score you need to check if it did return anything and output the score

```
if(l != my_vector.cend()){
    cout << "max=" << l->score;
}
```

Also a few tips:

- Don't do

  `#define n 3`

This is C++, and giving meaningful variable names is a good practice you can use

```
 constexpr int MAX_STUDENTS = 3;
```

- You aren't using `student::vrod()` and `student:dis()` methods anywhere

UPDATE (OP request):

Lambda expressions is a more convenient way to write functions for various uses. Lambda in this case

```
 [](const student& s1, const student& s2) {
    return s1.score < s2.score;
    }
```

is a more convenient way to write a comparator function, it can also be implemented with a functor

```
struct compare_students {
    bool operator() (const student& s1, const student& s2) const {
        return s1.score < s2.score;
    }
};
auto l = std::max_element(my_vector.cbegin(), my_vector.cend(), compare_students());
```

For more information please consider searching for C++ lambda tutorials and examples.

Comment: there is no such a thing as `std::max` that takes a range. What should it return if the range is empty?

Comment: using a `constexpr` for `MAX_STUDENTS` would be better still.

Comment: please explain a bit about ",
    [](const student& s1, const student& s2) " what is its function?

Comment: It's a *lambda* function. Click on the link that @buld0zzr has very helpfully provided.

Comment: @sam Added a small explanation, but to gain understanding you will have to search for more information yourself

Comment: I studied lambda in the net and used you code in c++ to find maximum,but I received error C2371: 'l' : redefinition; different basic types.Why?!

Comment: @sam remove l declaration from beginning of main function

Answer (score 1):

```
int max_score = std::max_element(
    my_vector.begin(),
    my_vector.end(),
    [] (student const& lhs, student const& rhs){
        return lhs.score < rhs.score;
    }
)->score;
```

is one way. Note the use of the *lambda* function acting as the *comparator*.

Pre C++11, you'd use a *function object* to model the comparator.

Comment: Here's one to you too since OP seems to have left elsewhere :)

Comment: please explain a bit about " [] (student const& lhs, student const& rhs){
        return lhs.score < rhs.score;
    } " what is its function?